# After throwing $5$ dice, what is the probability that they don't have all the same number?

Tags: probability, dice

We have $5$ fair dice. What is the probability that they don't have all the same number?

---

**Attempt**

We must have at least one die that is different of the others. My argument is:

Let distinguish the dice: we give to each dice a letter $a,b,c,d,e$. So, we need to have either $a$ different of every other die, or $b$ different of every other die or $c$ different of every other die or $d$ different of other dice or $e$ different of other dice. So, for $a$ different of every other dice, we hace $6$ possibilities for $b$, $6$ for $c$, $6$ possibilities for $d$, $6$ possibilities for $e$ and $5$ possibilities for $a$.  That make $6^45$ possibilities. For $b$ different of the other, we have the same: $6^4\cdot5$ possibilities as well, for $c$ the same... and so at the end, we get a probability of $\frac{6^4\cdot5}{6^5}\cdot5>1$, and thus it's wrong. The final result is $\frac{6^4}{5}\cdot6^5$ but I don't understand why my argument is not correct.

Comment: hint. Think about the event they all have the same number. Then take the complement.

Comment: @EDZ: I want to understand why my argument is not correct. By the way, I would say the same : 6 possibilities for the first dice, the others are determinate, or 6 possibilities for the 2nd dice, the other are determinated,... at the end I find $\frac{6\cdot 5}{6^5}$

Comment: Well I would calculate probability all are the same, which is just 1/6^4, then subtract 1 from that. But I believe the more important lesson here is when you get a probability over 1, you look for where you counted 2 possibilities that are not mutually exclusive. In this case A being different from B automatically makes B being different from dice A, and you are counting that possibility twice. Not to mention fixing dice A gives A 6 possibilities but dice B 5 possibilities to be different. (and the rest of the die 5 possibilities each)

Comment: @EDZ Rolling the same number with all die is not the complement event. You are missing the events where you roll $k$  die with the same number with $2\leq k\leq 5$

Comment: @calculus OP is asking for probability they don't ALL have the same number not ANY. So probability is 1 - probability all have the same number. Unless I'm misreading OP's question or OP worded it wrong.

Comment: @EDZ Oh yeah. You´re so right. I excuse my self.

Comment: "Dice" is itself  the plural of "die".  "Dices" is a verb meaning to cut into small cubes.

Comment: One fundamental flaw in your reasoning is that $a$ doesn’t have to be different from _all_ of the other dice, but only from _one_ of them, and similarly for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\boxed{7770/7776}$

There are only six ways in which the five dice can each have the same number: they can all equal $1$, they can all equal $2$, they can all equal $3$, etc.

But, we want the probability that they *don't* all have the same number.

There are $6^{5}$ total ways to choose the outcome of the $5$ dice, since there are $6$ outcomes for the first dice, $6$ for the second dice, and so on.

Thus, the number of desirable outcomes equals  $6^{5} - 6 = 7770$.

The probability of obtaining a desirable outcome is just the ratio of the number of desirable outcomes to total outcomes. This gives us $7770/6^{5} = 7770/7776,$ which is the answer.